# Hibernate case in Where statement

Tags: hibernate, case, member

Hi i try the following select: when the group attribute is set, the user has to be a member:

```
FROM Appointment a WHERE (CASE WHEN a.group!=null THEN :user MEMBER OF a.group.groupMembers ELSE true END)
```

But i get:

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: MEMBER near line 1, column 88 [FROM de.lyth.appointment.model.Appointment a WHERE (CASE when a.group!=null THEN :user MEMBER OF a.group.groupMembers ELSE true END) ]
```

how can i archieve this?

thanks

EDIT:
i solved it by changing to:

```
(a.group==null OR :user MEMBER OF a.group.groupMembers)
```

Comment: sorry i don't have enough reputation

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i solved it by changing to:
(a.group==null OR :user MEMBER OF a.group.groupMembers)

Comment: So does it mean the Case when is not supported in hql where clause?